# Find the number from the set that is not present in the array

Tags: python, arrays, loops, set

I was given this question in an interview: You are given a set of numbers {1..N} and an array A[N-1]. Find the number from the set that is not present in the array. Below is the code and pseudocode I have so far, that doesn't work.

I am assuming that there is one (and only one) number in the set that isn’t in the array

1. loop through each element in the set
2. loop through each element in the array O(n)
3. check to see if the number is in the array
4. if it is, do nothing
5. else, early return the number

```
def findMissingNo(arr, s):  
    for num in s: #loop through each element in the set
        for num2 in arr: ##loop through each element in the array O(n)
            if (num == num2): #if the number in the set is in the array, break 
                break
        print (num)
        return num #if the number in the set is not in the array, early return the number 
    return -1 #return -1 if there is no missing element 

s1 = {1,4,5}
arr1 = [1,4]

findMissingNo(arr1, s1)
```

Comment: Can't you just do `s1-set(arr1)`? The `-` on two sets performs a [difference](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.difference)

Answer (score 1):

By defination, we have a set from 1 to N  and a array of size N-1 , contains numbers from 1 to N , with one number missing and we have to find that number

since only 1 number is missing, and set has n element and array has n-1 element. so array is subset of set, with missing element as missing, that means

`all_number_of_set = all_number_of_array + missing_number`

also

`sum_of_all_number_of_set = sum_of_array_number + missing_number`

which implies

`missing_number = sum_of_all_number_of_set - sum_of_array_number`

pseudo code

```
def findMissingNo(set_, arr_ ):
      return sum(set_) - sum(arr_)
```

Comment: Elegant, completely bypasses the different nature of set and list. I suspect the interviewer wanted to test that, but would be happy with this answer.

Comment: @KennyOstrom i went through the OP definition of the problem, and yeah i suppose interviewer looking for basic mathematics knowledge, analytics ability and code optimization O(1).

Comment: @KennyOstrom plus as Op mentioned that set contains a number from 1..n and array has size n-1, with 1 number from set missing, so this approach, (this is common problem  asked in interview question)

Comment: I gave you +1, but I note that this approach is very dependent on well-behaved inputs. If you use the set difference functions built into python, you can tell if there are 0 or many answers.

Comment: thanks, this approach is dependent on the fact that, a set has N element and list/array has  n-1 element with no repeating. and element in set start from 0 to N and in list/array it is  from 0 to n with 1 element missing. this is OP statement. i think OP has given a wrong example to start with or didn't mention full statement, [this is the problem i guess](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-the-missing-number/)

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question well then you are finding the efficient way of finding the `set` number that do not exist in `list`. I see you are inner looping which would be `O(n^2)`. I would suggest to make the `dict` for the `list` which would be `O(n)` then find `O(1)` element in `dictionay` by looping over `set` `O(n)`. Considering large `list` with subset `set`:

```
def findMissingNo(arr_list, s_list):
    d = dict()
    for el in arr_list:
        d.update({el: el})
    for s in s_list:  
        try:
            d[s]
            pass
        except KeyError:
            return s
    return -1 

s1 = {1,4,5}
arr1 = [1,4]

findMissingNo(arr1, s1)
```

Hope it helps:)

Answer (score 0):

Your function is quadratic, because it has to check the whole list for each item in the set.

It's important that you don't iterate over the set. Yes, that can work, but you're showing that you don't know the time complexity advantages that you can get from a set or dict in python (or hashtables in general). But you can't iterate over the list either, because the missing item is ... missing. So you won't find it there.

Instead, you build a set from the list, and use the difference function. Or better, symmetric_difference (^) see https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#set

```
def findMissingNo(arr, s):        
    d = set(arr) ^ s # symmetric difference
    if 1 == len(d):
        for item in d:
            return item

print (findMissingNo([1,4], {1,4,5}))
```

> 5

I took a few shortcuts because I knew we wanted one item, and I knew which container it was supposed to be in. I decided to return None if no item was found, but I didn't check for multiple items.

Answer (score -3):

What about something like:

```
def findMissingNo(arr, s):
    for num in s:  # loop through each element in the set
        if num in arr:
            pass
        else:
            return num  # if the number in the set is not in the array, early return the number 
    return -1  # return -1 if there is no missing element
```

Comment: You could make this much smaller by removing the `pass`.

Comment: @KennyOstromcare to explain? First, there is no such thing as an array in Python. It is a list. Second, outside of different methods and lack of order, a set is basically a list.

Comment: It is very important that members of a set (or dict keys) can be found in O(1) time. I apologize for my dismissive tone, but your answer is wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I don't think my answer is wrong (it gets the job done and is a step in the right direction) but I agree it is far from being the best one.